# Autoscaling with Xen or XenServer

Tags: xen, xenserver, autoscaling

I need to learn how to implement autoscaling with a Xen platform or Citrix XenServer, just like it works on AWS. I made a search on Google, but I could not find something about that.

If my question is too broad and there's no a simple answer like "Enable feature X", I will appreciate your advice about what I should research to do it.

Answer (score 1):

No with only XenServer, you can enable WLB but it's only to distribute your host resource better between your VM.

[CloudPlatform is the product Citrix sell for that. (autoscale with your host)](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/netscaler/10-1/ns-system-wrapper-10-con/ns-autoscale-automatic-scaling-in-cloudplatform-env-wrapper-con/ns-autoscale-how-autoscale-works-con.html)

*Check step 3. You see that it manage your host.*

> When the CloudPlatform user submits the AutoScale configuration, the
>   following events occur:
>
> 1. CloudPlatform uses the NetScaler NITRO API to push the AutoScale configuration to the NetScaler appliance, creating AutoScale-related
>      entities on the appliance. The entities include a load balancing
>      virtual server, a service group, and monitors.
> 2. The AutoScale engine on the NetScaler appliance sends API requests to CloudPlatform to initially deploy the minimum number of virtual
>      machines required.
> 3. CloudPlatform provisions the minimum number of instances (VMs) on the hypervisors (virtualization hosts) that it manages.
> 4. The NetScaler appliance discovers the IP addresses assigned by CloudPlatform to the newly created VMs and binds them, as services, to
>      the service group representing them. The NetScaler appliance can then
>      load balance traffic to the VMs.
> 5. NetScaler monitors bound to the service group start monitoring the load by collecting SNMP metrics from the instances.
> 6. The AutoScale engine on the NetScaler appliance monitors the metrics collected from the VMs and triggers scale-up and scale-down
>      events whenever the metrics breach the configured threshold for the
>      specified period. As part of the scale-up trigger, the NetScaler
>      AutoScale engine sends an API request to CloudPlatform to deploy a new
>      VM. After the virtual machine is deployed, the AutoScale engine binds
>      the service representing the VM (IP address and port) to the service
>      group and, after the configured quiet time, starts forwarding load
>      balanced traffic to the new virtual machine. Likewise, as part of the
>      scale-down trigger, the NetScaler AutoScale engine selects a VM, stops
>      forwarding new requests to that instance, and waits for the configured
>      quiet time (to allow for the processing of current requests to
>      complete) before it sends an API request to CloudPlatform to destroy
>      the chosen instance.
>
> In this way, the NetScaler appliance monitors the application and
>   triggers scale-up and scale-down events on the basis of application
>   load and/or performance.